# Matlab ocv.dll error The Specified Module Could Not Be Loaded

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I am trying to use face detector of Matlab Vision Toolbox [Example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/face-detection-and-tracking-using-camshift.html)

I am getting this error when I run the script:

> MATLAB:dispatcher:loadLibrary Can't load 'C:\Program
>   Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\ocv.dll': The specified module could not
>   be found. Caught MathWorks::System::FatalException

My system is Win-64 and I don't have OpenCv installed on my system.What is the reason of getting this error ?

UPDATE: ocv.dll is existing in the specified location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenCV DLL comes with the Computer Vision System Toolbox for MATLAB. It sounds like the Computer Vision System Toolbox is not correctly installed on your computer.

Comment: Do you have an idea on getting rid of that? Also ı updated the question can you please check it